# ios7 navigation bar height resize using storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios7, storyboard, navigationbar

I just want to use navigation bar in `UIViewController`.

in iOS7, if we use navigation controller, the navigation bar height is 64px.

but when I use navigation bar in `UIViewController`, I can't change navigation bar height.

the height is fixed 44px.

How can I change navigation bar's height using Interface builder, not programming?

[image]

Apple doesn't support this feature in xcode storyboard?

Answer (score 6):

If you add a fixed height constraint to the UINavigationBar using autolayout, changing the height constraint constant will update the nav bar's height. You adjust this in the storyboard using the size inspector.

Before adding fixed height constraint:

[image: nav_bar_before]

After adding fixed height constraint:

[image: nav_bar_after]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Code:

```
@interface UINavigationBar (myNave)
- (CGSize)changeHeight:(CGSize)size;
@end


@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,70);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

For more info visit : http://tutorialmode.com/ios/customising-an-ios-navigation-bar/